# How to increase size of partition to take up unallocated space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have a Ubuntu installation(sda3) with unallocated space that I want to use to use to increase the space of sda5 on the following picture:

[image]

The only problem is I cant resize it, gparted says im already at the maximum size for that partition:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unallocated space needs to be contiguous to the partition to be resized. You will need to move swap to end of partition table first. Hope this helps.